# Amazon EC2 Free - Ports

Tags: c#, amazon-ec2

I have a small c# server that allows silverlight clients to connect to it.  Would I be able to host the server on a free 'EC2 running Microsoft Windows Server Micro' (Free signup gives you 750hr/mon of that for a year)?  I guess im asking if I could setup port 4530 on the server for I could communicate.  Would I need a dedicated IP to do this? (Which I assume isn't in the 'free' stuff), or if its not a dedicated, am I able to 'register' that port for data coming in knows to go to my 'server'?

Comment: elastic ip : dedicated ip -- Eric J. has the rest of your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, a Micro instance is still an instance... meaning it is a full virtual machine that just happens to have minimal resources (CPU, memory, and IO).

You should be able to allow any port you like using the Amazon instance management tools (you'll need to specifically allow that port for the relevant [security group](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html) for your instance).

http://cloud-computing.learningtree.com/2010/09/24/understanding-amazon-ec2-security-groups-and-firewalls/

UPDATE (based on sdolgy's comment)

You get an [Elastic IP](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1346) for you instance, meaning an IP address that remains constant even if e.g. your instance is moved within the AWS data center, the elastic IP remains the same.  You can manage elastic IP's via the AWS control panel.

Comment: and then on the silverlight clients, I'd use the elastic IP as the one to connect to?

Comment: @Will: Yes, you would use the elastic IP.  You probably however want to setup a DNS entry e.g. myserver.com that points to the elastic IP address.  Hard coding any sort of IP address into a client is never a good idea.

Comment: From what I read it says bandwidth from an elastic IP is counted as 1c/gb;  Is that correct, so I'd pay for any bandwidth my c# server uses?

Comment: @will: I'm not up on current AWS pricing.  I have not used AWS in the last year or so. Still, 1c/gb will be trivially cheap unless you're doing extremely high volume web transactions or streaming data (and if you're streaming something like video, there are better ways to do it).